# Google Compute Engine SSH - different username after switching to OS Login

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

I created a Compute Engine VM (Ubuntu 18.04), and when I log into it using the SSH button in the VM instances list I'm logged in as user `username`.

After a while, I realised I needed to be able to use another SSH client as well. As per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced I enabled OS Login by adding a key-value pair in metadata, where key is `enable-oslogin` and value is `TRUE`.

I then tried to add my existing SSH key:

`gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub --ttl 0`

which was successful except one major problem: it has added the key for user `username_gmail_com` and will only allow me to ssh to my VM as that user:

`ssh username_gmail_com@myinstance`

That's very inconvenient, because my code is at `/home/username` owned by `username`. So instead, I would like to be able to

`ssh username@myinstance`

Where did I go wrong, and what would be the best way to solve this?

ps. I also tried

`gcloud compute ssh username_gmail_com@myinstance
gcloud compute ssh username@myinstance`

which both give the `WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.` and offer to create it (which I haven't).

**===Edit**

I disabled OS Login, but then I can't ssh from my local console at all (of course, because that's what the docs say). The web interface console then logs in with the old username.

So with OS Login disabled for my project, Compute uses `username`. With OS Login enabled, it uses `username_gmail_com`. Any pointers to docs explaining why this is and how we can influence would be welcome.

My solution likely lies in reconfiguring the server for the new user (it's entirely possible that recreating it is easier). If anyone knows any other solution I'm interested to learn.